# how to export a checkbox to a .doc document in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I use OpenOffice through the java API, and make him open the .odt file, fill in some values and save as .doc and .pdf. The .doc have no checkboxes in it.

I'm basically looking for a workaround of [bug 45347](http://www.openoffice.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=45347)

Correcting the bug by myself is not an option since a checkout of the openoffice code takes more than 10h (various Go of stuff), and I never managed to carry out a compilation of it.

Thanks,

Nico.

Comment: If it's too much effort for you to fix the bug (your job I assume), do you really expect the _volunteer_ SO community to do so?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workaround 
Although I'm not a native english speaker, I don't think I made such big error in my text to be interpreted as such ?
Can you tell me what passage is confusing that I correct it please ?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but shouldn't this be on Super User..?

Comment: yes maybe, but I'm using it in my software, and I don't have an account there. And I just think a developer knows how to read a bug report, and what a workaround is (even if not everybody here does) and would have had investigated that in the past.

Comment: @Frank Krueger: I don't think fixing OpenOffice bugs is his job. His job is to build something that uses it. 
@nraynaud: Have you tried exporting to DOCX or what the new office format is called again? Maybe it behaves better there?

Comment: If you're using a java lib and you are sure of how to patch the appropriate classes, you can find the appropriate jar, decompile the classes, patch the src, recompile and rebuild the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would be the [Apache Java POI library](http://poi.apache.org) -- generate the document with OpenOffice, then open and modify it with the POI Microsoft Office API --
[here's someone's suggestion for a similar problem](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/poi-user/200804.mbox/%3Calpine.LFD.1.00.0804011519420.4860@localhost.localdomain%3E)